# How to add aggregated columns from SQL SELECT to AR object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Suppose we have a model `Order` and `Item` where `order` has_many `items`.

I'd now like to get the sum of all items for each order.

```
@orders = Order.select("orders.*, sum(items.amount) as items_sum)
              .joins("LEFT JOIN orders ON items.order_id = orders.id")
              .group("orders.id")
```

produces

```
SELECT sum(items.amount) as items_sum, transfers.* FROM "orders" 
LEFT JOIN items ON items.order_id = orders.id GROUP BY orders.id
```

The SQL itself works fine. The problem is that `@orders` doesn't include the `items_sum`. I'd like to be able to do `@orders[0].items_sum`. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to access it as

```
@orders.first.items_sum
```

or

```
@orders.first["items_sum"]
```

Documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select)

Comment: I can't. The object contains all database attributes from orders, but not `items_sum`

Comment: you won't see the attribute when you inspect the object. but you can access it. What do you get when you do `@orders[0].items_sum` ?

Comment: okay, I found the problem. In my original query and code I had ItemsSum CamelCased. However, the result column returned by PostgreSQL was "itemssum".